# browser extension compatibility - check if browser is chrome or firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, mozilla, firefox-addon-webextensions

I've a chrome extension to update that is distributed on chrome web store and on mozilla addons. I need to mantain the crossbrowser compatibility and I'm using polyfill to achieve this, but I have a small problem, the original background script use the `declarativeContent` API that is only available in chrome, since this will not work in firefox to activate the `pageAction` that is the extension rely on to work, Is there a solution to check if the browser is chrome or firefox in background script and then run the `declarativeContent` API or the `tabs.query` to call the `pageAction.show()` and activate the extension?

Comment: if (chrome.declarativeContent) { ... } else { ... }

Comment: @wOxxOm so it will return true if the api is available? On the documentation there isn't any info about, thank you for the help

Comment: It is easy to test this, alfaun0.. set up your Html snippet in a Notepad and press F5 in the browser. In Chrome, the pointer will be found and non-zero, therefore the true case is reached, because non-zero is tested. The chrome object does not exist in mozzilla browsers, so JS will simply break at the if-condition when the browser is non-chrome. In that case neither condition is reached. To make sure it works, set your chrome-flag in the true case.